# How to use Cookies and Sessions in Java Servlets and JSP pages?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, cookies

I have some problems using cookies and sessions in servlets and JSP pages. Can you please show an example about how both of them can be used? I need to create a session or a cookie and use them later, in other pages, but I don't know what methods should be called and in which order. I tried in many ways but I keep getting exceptions. My codes look like...

```
Cookie score = new Cookie("score", "0");
response.addCookie(score);

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("score", new Integer(0));
```

And in JSP file I try to retrieve them in the following way:

```
<%>Cookie[] c = request.getCookies();
   for(Cookie i : c)
      if(i.getName().equals("score"))
        System.out.println(i.getValue()); <%>
```

for cookies and...

```
<%> System.out.println(request.getAttribute("score")); <%>
```

for session. But both are null.

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be more helpful to you (and future users) if you show us what you currently have and where specifically you are having trouble (ie: any errors, exceptions). Questions asking for examples without any code are general considered off topic.

Comment: here is some code from my project related to the issue